# How to enable HTTPS on a SpringBoot 2.0.5 application

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy

I need to enable HTTPS on a Spring Boot 2.0.5 application with a self-signed certificate, however, everything I've found so far in configurations is related to setting a property named
`security.require-ssl=true`
but it seems that on this Spring Boot version that property is deprecated... is any other way for enabling HTTPS on a Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) which recommends to use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instead of the `secure.*` properties. Using matchers you can have fine grained control when to enforce SSL, or just do something similar to ...

```
 http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure() (...)
```

... in your Adapter configuration to enforce *https* for any request.

Comment: Also I found that the property `server.ssl.enabled = true` started the application in https at the specified port, plus the porpertis related to the keystore/certificate